# Why Dancer `halt` command bypass all events?

Tags: perl, dancer

Example:

```perl
hook on_route_exception => sub {
    # This code is not executed  
}

hook on_handler_exception => sub {
    # This code is not executed  
}

hook after => sub {
    # This code is not executed  
}


hook after_error_render => sub {
    # This code is not executed  
}

hook before => sub {
    if ($some_condition) {
        halt("Unauthorized");
        # This code is not executed :
        do_stuff();
    }
};
 
get '/' => sub {
    "hello there";
};
```

I can find [this piece](https://metacpan.org/pod/Dancer#halt) of documentation:

> Thus, any code after a halt is ignored, until the end of the route.

But hooks are after the end of route, so should not be ignored. Should be?

Why hooks are ignored too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would think that the reason is that the processing was halted.  The

```
halt("Unauthorized");
```

would essentially return that content in the response object and no further events are required.  The halt effectively halted all processing for that request/response.

That is a guess based on how it is behaving and the description.

A closer look at :https://metacpan.org/release/BIGPRESH/Dancer-1.3513/source/lib/Dancer.pm#L156

shows that after the Response Content is set to "Unauthorized" it calls:

```
Dancer::Continuation::Halted->new->throw
```

which dies:

https://metacpan.org/release/BIGPRESH/Dancer-1.3513/source/lib/Dancer/Continuation.pm#L14

```
sub throw { die shift }
```

At least that's how I read that code.  Since it dies there is nothing else to do.

Likely a deliberate design decision based on the intention to halt.

Comment: Probably this is good decision, but it so implicit and not documented... ((